# I was attempting the 'Contains Duplicate' problem on Leetcode. My code seems fine but I am receiving the Time limit exceeded error

Tags: java, arrays

Is there a better way to solve this problem through nested loops, or Hashtable (or any other methods)are the only way to deal with this error?

```
class Solution {
    public boolean containsDuplicate(int[] nums) {
        // traversing the array to find an element equal to the chosen element
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
            // now after one element is chosen traversing the rest to find its equal
            for (int j = i+1; j < nums.length; j++){
                int dupli = nums[i];
                if (dupli == nums [j]){
                    return true;
                }                
            }
        }
     return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Compiler errors on your English sentence. Follow up on your hash table idea.

Comment: _"Is there a better way to solve this problem through nested loops"_ - Why do you assume a nested loop is the best way? "Time limit exceeded" sounds like your algorithm takes too long to complete given a _large_ input. You will probably want to find an O(n) solution (single loop) to not get this error (rather than O(n^2)).

Comment: I am a beginner and can't think of a better solution, I didn't necessarily mean nested loops. I meant to ask if it can be solved by loops in a better approach, which won't give the TLE error without using concepts like hashmap as I am not versed in it.